# Postgres partitioned tables with dynamic where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a partitioned table that I'm using to get the sum of X column for the records with Y column.

If I use

```
where logdate >= '2020-01-01' AND logdate < '2020-02-01'
```

I get a *clean* query plan and execution, while if I do

```
where logdate >= (SELECT CURRENT_DATE - 30) AND logdate < '2020-02-01'
```

really, `SELECT CURRENT_DATE - 30` is just an example to show the initial date is going to be generated *dynamically* - it traverses all the partitioned with bitmap heap scans and index scans resulting in a query execution 10 times slower.

Is there something I can do in order improve the query for that given part (the where clause), or should I resign and try instead manipulating the dates with the programming language I'm currently using?

Comment: If you really need partitioning for performance you shouldn't be using 9.5 to  begin with. Upgrade to 12 and switch to declarative partitioning

Comment: I'd like to, but it's not possible by now @a_horse_with_no_name, nothing to do, then?

Comment: No. The best you can do is to construct SQL statements where you use only literal values.

Comment: Nice. I don't know if any of you guys want to write an answer, if it deserves to be answered.